# Why don't terminal colors match browser colors?

Tags: javascript, node.js, browser, terminal, colors

I am using `const supportsColor = require('supports-color')` and `yellow: s => chalk.hex('#e4ba61')(s)` chalk to set the color of a string. Why is there a difference between the colors the browser shows vs. what my iTerm2 supposedly "16 million color supporting" terminal shows?

[image]

Purple looks pretty close, green looks somewhat close but not quite, yellow doesn't look close at all as seen in this picture. The terminal looks orange. Is the only way to make it match to visually match it, or what is going on?

Comment: Consistent colour across different software has been a struggle for decades. Even different monitors on the same machine will show different colours for the same hex value. What terminal are you using? How do you know that it is not only showing 256 colours?

Comment: Also see https://gist.github.com/sindresorhus/bed863fb8bedf023b833c88c322e44f9

Comment: I am on a mac using iTerm2, and the `supports-color` says `supportsColor.stdout.has16m`.